# Meteor angular ui-router ui-sref works in one case, not another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I'm building an angular meteor app with a mongoDB Collection that with this structure:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "9YFoLcpDKFbJjHDoN", 
    "name" : "Negative Thought 1", 
    "betterThoughts" : [ 
                         { 
                            "name" : "bt", 
                            "_id" : ObjectId("cdb4533e03a0a430b02320af") 
                         } 
                       ] 
}
```

The app has the following structure with three depths

1. Home: contains list of negative thoughts
2. Negative thought: contains list of better thoughts
3. Better thought details

Clicking a negative thought in level 1 leads to that negative thought in level 2. This works. Clicking a better thought in level 2 however does not lead to that better thought's details in level 3.

My UI Router .config looks like this:

```
angular.module('better-thoughts').config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
    .state('thoughts', {
      url: '/thoughts',
      template: '<negs-list></negs-list>'
    })
    .state('betterThoughts', {
      url: '/thoughts/:negId',
      template: '<better-thoughts></better-thoughts>'
    })
    .state('betterThoughtDetails', {
      url: '/thoughts/:negId/:betterThoughtId',
      template: '<better-thought-details></better-thought-details>'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/thoughts");
});
```

So the first 2 states work fine, the third one does not.

In the thoughts (level 1) list of negative thoughts html I have this code to link to the next state (betterThoughts):

```
 <li ui-sref="betterThoughts({ negId: neg._id })" ng-repeat="neg in negsList.negs">
    {{neg.name}}
    <button ng-click="negsList.removeNeg(neg)">X</button>
  </li>
```

Again, this works.

In the better-thoughts (level 2) list of better thoughts I have the following to link to the next state (betterThought Details):

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref="betterThoughtDetails({ betterThoughtId: betterThoughts.neg.betterThought._id})"
  ng-repeat="betterThought in betterThoughts.neg.betterThoughts">
    {{betterThought.name}} </br>
    {{betterThought._id._str}}
    <button ng-click="betterThoughts.removeBetterThought(betterThought)">X</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This does not work.

I'll just include the directive for betterThoughts (level 2) to save space.

```
angular.module('better-thoughts').directive('betterThoughts', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/negs/better-thoughts/better-thoughts.html',
    controllerAs: 'betterThoughts',
    controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $reactive) {
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);

      this.newBetterThought = {};

      this.helpers({
        neg: () => {
          return Negs.findOne({ _id: $stateParams.negId });
        }
      });

      this.save = () => {
        Negs.update({_id: $stateParams.negId}, {
          $set: {
            name: this.neg.name,
          }
        }, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to update the thought...');
          }
          else {
            console.log('Done!', $stateParams);
          }
        });
      };

      this.addBetterThought = () => {
        Negs.update(
          { _id : $stateParams.negId },
          {
            $push:
              { betterThoughts: {
                name : this.newBetterThought.name,
                _id : new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID()
              }
            }
          }
        );
        this.newBetterThought = {};
      };

      this.removeBetterThought = (betterThought) => {
        Negs.update(
          { _id : $stateParams.negId },
          {
            $pull: {
              betterThoughts: {
                _id: betterThought._id
              }
            }
          }
        );
      };


    }
  };
});
```

Here's a link to my repo in case important information is missing: https://bitbucket.org/mandyschippers/better-thoughts

Why does the link from level 1 to level 2 work, but not the link from level 2 to level 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a few things and found the solution myself. It was to change ui-sref to the following:

```
betterThoughtDetails({
   betterThoughtId : betterThought._id._str
```

to get the ._str property of the ObjectId object.